# Unconditional layout, crash on layoutInflater.inflate

Tags: java, android

I get warning about Unconditional layout + crash of the app on line:

View activity_dealer = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dealer, parent, false);

could you please check it out? 
In debbug mode I get also msg about:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.testcase:layout/activity_dealer: Binary XML file line #8 in com.example.testcase:layout/toolbar: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.example.testcase:layout/toolbar: Error inflating class
```

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar


public class DealerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] mTitle = {"USA", "Europe", "Germany", "Asia"};
    String[] mDescribtion = {"USA Describtion", "Europe Describtion", "Germany Describtion", "Asia Describtion"};
    int[] images = {R.drawable.asia, R.drawable.usa, R.drawable.europe, R.drawable.germany};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dealer);

        //listview dealer
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        DealerActivity.MyAdapter adapter = new DealerActivity.MyAdapter(this, mTitle, mDescribtion, images);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(DealerActivity.this,"USA activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (position == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(DealerActivity.this,"Europe activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (position == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(DealerActivity.this,"Germany activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (position == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(DealerActivity.this,"Asia activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Worldwide");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        Context context;
        String[] rTitle;
        String[] rDescribtion;
        int[] rImgs;

        MyAdapter (Context c, String[] title, String[] describtion, int[] imgs){
            super(c, R.layout.activity_dealer, R.id.textview1, title);
            this.context = c;
            this.rTitle = title;
            this.rDescribtion = describtion;
            this.rImgs = imgs;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View activity_dealer = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dealer, parent, false);

            ImageView images = activity_dealer.findViewById(R.id.image);
            TextView myTitle = activity_dealer.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            TextView myDescribtion = activity_dealer.findViewById(R.id.textview2);


            images.setImageResource(rImgs[position]);
            myTitle.setText(rTitle[position]);
            myDescribtion.setText(rDescribtion[position]);

            return activity_dealer;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is activity_dealer.xml attached
Inside is very simple ListView, ImageView and TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:text="Please choose your region"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Main title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Sub title"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: please post activity_dealer.xml

Comment: @LenaBru - xml attached on top

Comment: please post toolbar.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for inflate in getview method

```
 View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_dealer, parent, false);
```

or

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    String[] rTitle;
    String[] rDescribtion;
    int[] rImgs;

    MyAdapter (Context c, String[] title, String[] describtion, int[] imgs){         
        this.context = c;
        this.rTitle = title;
        this.rDescribtion = describtion;
        this.rImgs = imgs;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItem holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolderItem();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dealer, parent, false);
            holder.images = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.images);
            holder.myTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
            holder.myDescribtion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myDescribtion);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.images.setImageResource(rImgs[position]);
        holder.myTitle.setText(rTitle[position]);
        holder.myDescribtion.setText(rDescribtion[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         return 4;
     }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help for you